# What can be done to get the heat-flow probe next to the Insight lander moving downwards again?

Tags: mars, insight, heat-flow

[This article of July 12,2019](https://nasaspaceflight.com/2019/07/rescue-insight-landers-stuck-probe-underway/) tells us that in late June 2019 NASA engineers succesfully lifted off the [HP³](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_Flow_and_Physical_Properties_Package) support structure of the Martian surface and obtained a clear view of the half-submerged heat-flow probe, also nicknamed "ẗhe mole".
[image]

The image above from [this Spacenews article](https://spacenews.com/insight-mission-seeking-new-ways-to-fix-heat-flow-probe/) shows the current position of the probe in the Martian soil with a gap around the mole.

Imprints from the scoop at the end of Insight's robotic arm near the gap show the attempts to collapse the hole around the probe to get more friction from the soil.

New ways are considered to get the mole moving again, such as pinning it with the scoop.

To me, a thinkable solution would be to use the robotic arm to grapple the tail of the mole and to pull horizontally to get the probe vertical while it's hammering to allow it to pass the obstacle.

**Question:** Are there other credible solutions to get the heat-flow probe moving downwards again ?